# why oracle can update pk=pk+1,but MySQL can not update set pk=pk+1

Tags: mysql, oracle, primary-key

ORACLE:

```
 create table t7(c1 number primary key,c2 number);
 insert into t7 values (1,3);
 insert into t7 values (2,4);
 commit;
 update t7 set c1=c1+1;
 commit ;
 select * from t7;
```

MySQL:

```
 create table t7(c1 int primary key,c2 int);
 insert into t7 values (1,3);
 insert into t7 values (2,4);
 select * from t7;
 update t7 set c1=c1+1;
 ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Why does MySQL says

> `update set pk=pk+1 :Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'`,

Whereas ORACLE can do this `update set pk=pk+1`?

Comment: Interesting. I guess it depends how the rows are fetched while running the update statement. If second  row is updated before first row then you won't get this as by then 2 would have been updated to 3 already. I bet if you try the Oracle thing over a few thousand rows, you will get similar error.

Comment: @Noob the primary key restraints are only temporarily violated. after the update is complete all values are once again unique, which is why updating in reverse order (starting with the largest) works fine, even in mysql.

Comment: @Utsav in hindsight I would blame having to explicitely commit changes in oracle. if the Update happens in a "transaction" and the constraints are only checked once you try to commit changes it wont notice the overlapping keys during the update. this is of course wild speculation since i have 0 knowledge or experience with oracle.

Comment: @user3141593 - nice guess, but no. If you try to update the primary key from 1 to 2 (without updating the other row), you will get an error - even if you don't commit (you won't get the option to, since the UPDATE statement will result in an error).

Comment: This is interesting as a piece of research. However, in real life you should never want to update the primary key, because they ought to be unchanged for the life of the record.

Answer (score 2):

it seems oracle is either smarter about the execution order, or only checks constraints after applying the update to all rows. anyhow , the mysql example can be fixed by specifying the order on the update.

```
 create table t7(c1 int primary key,c2 int);
 insert into t7 values (1,3);
 insert into t7 values (2,4);
 select * from t7;
 update t7 set c1=c1+1 order by c1 desc;
```

see **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8611f4/1**

Trying to update the first row to (2,3) is a duplicate key since (2,4) still has the old values. The workaround for this behavior is to reverse the Order and start with the largest index, changing (2,4) -> (3,4) and then (1,3) -> (2,3), and avoiding the collision altogether.

Comment: Technically speaking, the "logical fix" is to treat the operation as applying to a set (that is: logically the update is applied to all rows simultaneously). I don't know **how** Oracle implements that (since, indeed, in real life rows must be updated one at a time); most likely it updates all the rows, in whatever order, and only then it checks if all the constraints are still satisfied. But logically - how we should **think** about it - is as a set operation.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the insight, youre absolutely right. I guess I am guilty of constructing a "broken" implementation and then "working around it" in my head, instead of sticking to what a DB should be. even my speculations on the question were limited to implementation details instead of how the system should aim to behave.

Answer (score 1):

In Relational Databases, there is conceptually limited meaning (not to say not at all) to update your primary key.

Oracle implemented this, whereas MySQL didn't. You discovered it.

If you really want to do what you intend, solution is to insert new record, then remove previous.

To do it on the whole table, better create a temporary table. Here is how it looks:

```
create table t7_tmp(c1 int primary key,c2 int);
insert into t7_tmp (select c1+1,c2 from t7);
delete t7;
insert into t7 (select c1,c2 from t7_tmp);
drop table t7_tmp;
```